# Nested Archive navigation

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to replicate the following markup in an Archive navigation in my wordpress theme.

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>2012
    <ul>
      <li>December
        <ul>
          <li>Page 1</li>
          <li>Page 2</li>
          <li>Page 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>November
        <ul>
          <li>Page 1</li>
          <li>Page 2</li>
          <li>Page 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have the following php so far from another post, how can i update this code to output like my html year/month/post titles?

```
    <?php

// Declare some helper vars
$previous_year = $year = 0;
$previous_month = $month = 0;
$ul_open = false;

// Get the posts
$myposts = get_posts('numberposts=-1&orderby=post_date&order=DESC&cat=13');

?>

<?php foreach($myposts as $post) : ?>   

    <?php

    // Setup the post variables
    setup_postdata($post);

    $year = mysql2date('Y', $post->post_date);
    $month = mysql2date('n', $post->post_date);

    ?>

    <?php if($year != $previous_year || $month != $previous_month) : ?>

        <?php if($ul_open == true) : ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <h3><?php the_time('F Y'); ?></h3>

        <ul class="month_archive">

        <?php $ul_open = true; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php $previous_year = $year; $previous_month = $month; ?>

    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my code, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the built-in `wp_get_archives()`?

`<?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly' ) ); ?>`

Refer to the [Codex for more info on this method](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives).

**Update**

Try one of the plugins suggested at the end of this WP Forum post: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/list-posts-by-year-and-month-archive-like

They are quite old now, I'm not sure if they still work.

Comment: How can i use that to achieve what i want (see html)?

Comment: I've had a look at these, i need to write something in my own php though